# How to select top x from with params?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Sql-Server 2005

I have Users table with userID and gender. I want to select top 1000 males(0) and top 1000 females(1) order by userID desc.

If i create union only one result set is ordered by userID desc. What other way to do that?

```
SELECT top 1000 *
FROM Users
where gender=0
union
SELECT top 1000 *
FROM Users
where gender=1
order by userID desc
```

Comment: Can you post the SQL of your query? Specifically I'm wondering about things like parentheses and the location or your 'order by' clause.

Comment: By what criterion do you intend to choose the top 1000? At the moment the query above the union is choosing effectively at random.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos, top 1000 males and top 1000 females ordered by highest userID thus the latest top 1000 males and latest top 1000 females.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Looks like both the query below and above the union choose at random.  The `order by` is done after both parts of the union have finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it

```
WITH TopUsers AS
(
SELECT UserId, 
       Gender,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY UserId DESC) AS RN
  FROM Users
  WHERE Gender IN (0,1) /*I guess this line might well not be needed*/
) 

SELECT UserId, Gender 
FROM TopUsers  
WHERE RN <= 1000
ORDER BY UserId DESC
```

Comment: A much more elegant solution than mine. Performs better too. I will remember that. Thanks.

Comment: What i will do without you, Martin Smith? I end up with 90% of answers from  you!

Answer (score 3):

Martin Smith's solution is better than the following.

```
SELECT UserID, Gender
FROM 
  (SELECT TOP 1000 UserId, Gender 
   FROM Users 
   WHERE gender = 0
   ORDER BY UserId DESC) m
UNION ALL
SELECT UserID, Gender
FROM 
 (SELECT TOP 1000 UserId, Gender
  FROM Users
  WHERE gender = 1
  ORDER BY UserId DESC) f
ORDER BY Gender, UserID DESC
```

This does what you want, just change the order by if you'd rather have the latest user first, but it will get you the top 1000 of each.

Comment: +1 You're right, I focussed on the ordering and missed that he wanted the top 1000 per gender

Comment: Close, but if you order by Gender at the end then you split the males and females apart again.

Comment: @eugeneK I can't see another way to do it in one query, you can create a temporary table, insert the top 1000 of each into that, but I don't think it would be quicker. It'll be interesting if some knows a way though :D

Comment: PS Whoever down voted can you please point out the error in the query, because I can't see one. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Diver, whoever voted down doesn't matter because your query is the only query out of all answers that did the job correctly. I don't know how and why. Tbh i don't care.

Comment: @Chris Diver That's better now without the Gender in the order by at the end. :-)

Comment: @eugeneK - I thought that the answer was wrong in some way that I hadn't seen, glad its not.

Comment: @Chris Diver, Tom is right that Gender at the end is useless to me but i haven't specified that in my question so you answer still right even though i've removed Gender from order by at first.

Comment: @Chris. You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this. Does that count as a single query solution?

Comment: @Martin it's still a subquery, but it is far better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Done some testing, and the results are pretty strange.  If you specify an `order by` in both parts of a union, SQL Server gives a syntax error:

```
select top 2 * from @users where gender = 0 order by id
union all
select top 2 * from @users where gender = 1 order by id
```

That makes sense, because the order by should only be at the end of the union.  But if you use the same construct in a subquery, it compiles! And works as expected:

```
select * from (
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 0 order by id
    union all
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 1 order by id
) sub
```

The strangest thing happens when you specify only one `order by` for the subquery union:

```
select * from (
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 0
    union all
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 1 order by id
) sub
```

Now it orders the first half of the union at random, but the second half by id.  That's pretty unexpected.  The same thing happens with the `order by` in the first half:

```
select * from (
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 0 order by id desc
    union all
    select top 2 * from @users where gender = 1
) sub
```

I'd expect this to give a syntax error, but instead it orders the first half of the union.  So it looks like `union` interacts with `order by` in a different way when the `union` is part of a subquery.

Like Chris Diver originally posted, a good way to get out of the confusion is not to rely on the `order by` in a union, and specify everything explicitly:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        from    (
                select  top 2 *
                from    @users
                where   gender = 0
                order by 
                        id desc
                ) males
        union all
        select  *
        from    (
                select  top 2 *
                from    @users
                where   gender = 1
                order by 
                        id desc
                ) females
        ) males_and_females
order by 
        id
```

Example data:

```
declare @users table (id int identity, name varchar(50), gender bit)

insert into @users (name, gender)
          select 'Joe', 0
union all select 'Alex', 0
union all select 'Fred', 0
union all select 'Catherine', 1
union all select 'Diana', 1
union all select 'Esther', 1
```

Comment: @Chris Diver: Your query does work.  I'm writing out even more explicitly what the final `order by` applies to

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you create a sub-select for the union, then do the ordering outside over the combined results.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM (SELECT u1a.* FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 u1.*
                             FROM USERS u1
                            WHERE u1.gender = 0
                            ORDER BY u1.userid DESC) u1a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT u2a.* FROM (SELECT TOP 1000 u2.*
                             FROM USERS u2
                            WHERE u2.gender = 1
                            ORDER BY u2.userid DESC) u2a
       ) u
ORDER BY u.userid DESC
```

Also, using a UNION ALL will give better performance as the db won't bother checking for duplicates (which there won't be in this query) in the results.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but it will select top males and females based on what factor, i guess no factor?

Comment: Close but that won't work it will select any 1000 users who are male and any 1000 that are female, he wants the latest 1000

Comment: Don't think you can have an `order by` in both parts of a union, only one at the end is allowed

Comment: @Andomar, strangely enough it is working just does not give proper results. I was thinking the same thus executed it to correct Tom.

Comment: @Tom, my highest userID is 70000 and your query's highest userID is 54000

Comment: +1 The last two versions of this answer worked on my machine, even though they were posted later than Chris'

Comment: @eugineK really? I can't see how, but I believe you. Is that with the query as it stands now, or an earlier version?

Comment: Didn't work for me either `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'`, need to give the sub queries a table name. `ORDER BY u1.UserID DESC) tablename UNION ALL`